# How to deque and then enque in one function C programming

Tags: c

I built a queue with a struct in C. Trying to built a function that dequeues and enqueues
the same node with the inicio() function, but it enters a loop every time. I'm new
programming in C, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance. I tried to built the function inicio() merging the functions dequeue and enqueue.

```
typedef struct  Nodo
{
 int valor;
 struct Nodo* sig;
 }Nodo;

void enque(Nodo** p,int v)
{
  Nodo *nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  nuevo->valor=v;
  if (*p==NULL)
  {
    nuevo->sig=nuevo;
  }
  else
 {
   nuevo->sig=(*p)->sig;
   (*p)->sig=nuevo;
 }
 *p=nuevo;
}

int deque(Nodo** p)
{
int ret=(*p)->sig->valor;

if(*p==(*p)->sig)
{
 free(*p);
 *p=NULL;
}
else
{
 Nodo* aux = (*p)->sig;
 (*p)->sig=aux->sig;
 free(aux);
 }
 return ret;
}

 void inicio(Nodo** p)
 {
   Nodo* aux = (*p)->sig;

  (*p)->sig=aux->sig;
    //free(aux);

  Nodo *nuevo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  nuevo = aux;
   nuevo->valor=aux->valor;

    nuevo->sig=(*p)->sig;
   (*p)->sig=nuevo;
   *p=nuevo;
 }

  int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  {
    Nodo* p = NULL;
    int v = 0;
    char c = 0;
    int r = 0;

    while(c!='n')
    {
      printf("Llenar\n");
      v++;
      enque(&p,v);
      printf("%d\n",v);
      scanf("%c",&c);
    }

   inicio(&p);


   printf("\n");
   mostrar2(&p,r);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: <O/T> _Trying to built a function that dequeues and enqueues the same node with the `inicio()` function...I tried to built the function inicio() merging the functions dequeue and enqueue_. I don't know why you'd want to do this, but `inicio` should call the `enque` and `deque` functions to accomplish this. That's one major benefit of writing functions.. reusable code. As it is now, you have two places to maintain and fix bugs for each of these operations.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the 'next ' link to NULL (I assume thats what 'sig' is)

At the moment you force a loop

```
nuevo->sig=nuevo;
```

You have a node pointing to itself as the next

You should set sig to NULL for the first (or maybe last), not sure how its supposed to work